# imageMagick fails at socket instance

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm using the imageMagick subclass of graphicsmagick to alter ~7k png images. The function below gets about 2/3 of the way through and fails (see log).

Seems to be an issue where a socket is failing. How do I debug this?

A thought I have is to use the [-limit method](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#limit), but no dice...

Thanks in advance :)

Code:

```html
// changing an image's resolution is the same thing as changing its DPI
export default async function changeScreenshotResolution(dimension) {
    new Promise(() => {
        try {
            const screenshots = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, `../output/screenshots/${dimension}`), function(error) {if (error) console.log(error)});
            
            screenshots.map(screenshot => {
                try {
                    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, `../output/screenshots/${dimension}/${screenshot}`));
                    let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, `../output/screenshots/${dimension}1/${screenshot}`));

                    im(readStream, screenshot)
                        .limit('memory', '32MB') // i tried variations of this but it made no difference
                        .units('PixelsPerInch')
                        .density(300,300)
                        .stream()
                        .pipe(writeStream)
                        
                    console.log(screenshot);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(`Error changing screenshot resolution: ${error}`);
                }
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`changeScreenshotResolution error: ${error}`);
        }
    })
};
```

```html
Error: spawn convert EAGAIN
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: -35,
  code: 'EAGAIN',
  syscall: 'spawn convert',
  path: 'convert',
  spawnargs: [
    '-density',
    '300x300',
    '/Users/daddy/Dev/scout/project-sunroof-scraping/output/screenshots/rect/6550 ARABIAN CIR.png',
    '-units',
    'PixelsPerInch',
    '/Users/daddy/Dev/scout/project-sunroof-scraping/output/screenshots/rect1/6550 ARABIAN CIR.png'
  ]
}
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ENOTCONN
    at tryReadStart (net.js:571:20)
    at Socket._read (net.js:582:5)
    at Socket.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:474:10)
    at Socket.read (net.js:622:39)
    at new Socket (net.js:374:12)
    at Object.Socket (net.js:265:41)
    at createSocket (internal/child_process.js:313:14)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:436:23)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:548:9)
    at spawn (/Users/daddy/Dev/scout/project-sunroof-scraping/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:17:18)
    at gm._spawn (/Users/daddy/Dev/scout/project-sunroof-scraping/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:224:14)
    at /Users/daddy/Dev/scout/project-sunroof-scraping/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:101:12
    at series (/Users/daddy/Dev/scout/project-sunroof-scraping/node_modules/array-series/index.js:11:36)
    at gm._preprocess (/Users/daddy/Dev/scout/project-sunroof-scraping/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:177:5)
    at gm.write (/Users/daddy/Dev/scout/project-sunroof-scraping/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:99:10)
    at /Users/daddy/Dev/scout/project-sunroof-scraping/modules/changeScreenshotDPI.js:18:26
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:100:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: -57,
  code: 'ENOTCONN',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```